# Perl: UDP Packet receive timeout handling with processes

Tags: perl, connection-timeout

Now I am designing a GUI for my sensor network with Perl-TK.
The main problem is that sometimes my low power lossy network suffers from packet loss. In that case my perl program stucks for example in the handshake. The handshakes run in different processes. I would like to yell for the user when the packet don't received and close the thread

Is there any solutions for implement any timeout for kill processes?

edit: 
It works with the main loop. But In a specific process it doesn't work, the program running stopped and the terminal drops "Alarm clock".
The half result is:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use Thread;
use IO::Socket::IP;
use Net::IP;
use Time::Out qw(timeout);
use warnings;

$conn_timeout = 2;
$th1=Thread->create(\&thr1);
while(1)
    {
        sleep(2);
        print"main proc\n";
    } 
sub  thr1{
 print "thread started\n";
        $temp = '2001:4428:29a::280:e103:1:57a8';
        $ip=Net::IP::ip_expand_address($temp, 6);
        $tempsock = IO::Socket::IP ->new(
                PeerAddr => $ip,
                PeerPort => '52525',
                Proto    => 'udp',
        ) or die "Cannot construct socket, IP address: $ip - error message: - $@";
        print "Socket opened successfully for $ip on port 52525\n";
        $SIG{ALRM} = sub {print "detaching...\n";thr1->detach(); }; # NB: \n required
        alarm $conn_timeout;
        $tempsock ->send("asdasd");
        $tempsock->recv($tempdata, 16);
        alarm 0;
}
```

edit 2:
[Can not use alarm in threads...](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=839249) So I have to measure the timeout in the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `alarm` and signal capture the exception that occurs from it. `alarm` original intent was socket connections, but it can be used for anything that takes awhile to run:

```
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required
    alarm $timeout;
    $nread = sysread SOCKET, $buffer, $size;
    alarm 0;
};
if ($@) {
    print ("Timeout occurred") unless $@ eq "alarm\n";   # propagate unexpected errors
    # timed out
}
else {
    # didn't
}
```

Comment: I inserted this, and it doesn't yells:`code`
$tempsock ->send("asdasd");
local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required
      alarm $conn_timeout;
      $tempsock->recv($tempdata, 16);

if ($@) {
print ("Timeout occurred") unless $@ eq "alarm\n";   # propagate unexpected errors
    # timed out
}

Comment: what? I don't understand, rephrase

Comment: Sorry, I'm beginner and I would like to write down my code here, how can I insert formatted source code? :) As you see above...

Comment: @Nolex: In comments you can use backticks to format things `like this` but no new lines. Best would be to edit your questions with the new information. In Questions and answers you can format code as narathaus did by indenting it 4 spaces. There is also a button to do that for pasted stuff at once.

Comment: @nrathaus It works fine, when in the main loop. But when I use in a specific process, when the time is up, it dies, but no "die" in the sub. The terminal drops "Alarm Clock" and the program halt.

Comment: Probably there is another signal handler of some kind somewhere OR you are spawning a process and the signal goes to the parent?

Comment: Oh, I see what you wrote, try IO::Socket::Timeout - https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::Timeout